# Ajax doesn't send data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

I am learning to use [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax). By clicking a submit button in a form, does not send data.

Jquery code:

```
 $('input[name="login"]').click(function()  {
    var username = $('#username').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/?module=login&special_content=true',
        data:{'username':username,'password':password, 'action':'login'},
        success: function(e) {
            if(e == false)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                document.location.href = e;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<section style="width: 400px; margin: 10% auto; float: none;" id="box">
<section id="box-header">
    <div id="box-title">%header_login%</div>
</section>
<section id="box-content" style="float: none;">
    <form method="POST" action="./">
        %login_username%<br>
        <input type="text" style="width: 100%;" class="input" name="username" placeholder="%login_input_user%" required/><br>
        %login_password%<br>
        <input type="password" style="width: 100%;" class="input" name="password" placeholder="%login_input_pass%" required/><br>
        <input type="button" id="login-button" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;" class="btn btn-red" name="login" value="%login_button%" />
    </form>
    <center><div style="margin-top: 5px;"> %login_or% <a href="?module=register">%login_signup%</a></div></center>
</section>
```

Where is the error? Thanks!

Comment: not quite enough information here. how far have you gone in debugging?

Comment: how are you checking?  you can use your browsers network tab to see the request going out and the response going back.  you can also use it see if there are errors in your JS code

Comment: $('#username') and $('#password') are not defined, you forgot the IDs.

Comment: What does the serverside code look like?

Comment: Your ajax will be skipped if the user presses "enter" instead of clicking submit, fyi. (which many users will do.) Either remove the form tags, or change your submit button to type="submit" and listen for the form's submit event rather than the submit button's click event.

Comment: Just do this:

`$('login-button').click(`

Not totally sure what the error is but you maybe confusing the browser by telling it that the input is a button. You could also try removing the `type="button"` and setting it to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused by your selectors. `$("#username")` means you want an element with the `id` set to "username".

For your two text inputs, change `name="username"` and `name="password"` to `id="username"` and `id="password"` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `#username` and `#password` don't exist thus the `.val()` returns empty/null.

Change the selector to `input[name=` will fix the problem

```
$('input[name="login"]').click(function()  {
    var username = $('input[name=username]').val();
    var password = $('input[name=password]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/?module=login&special_content=true',
        data:{'username':username,'password':password, 'action':'login'},
        success: function(e) {
            if(e == false)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                document.location.href = e;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgjBh/

check post requests with devtools ass seen in picture

[image: Ajaxing data]

Comment: Thanks, but still does not send data

Comment: I added a sreenshot showing the data being pushed/ajaxed.